# Mpdf on Codeigniter can't generate morris line chart

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf, morris.js

I'm using [Mpdf](https://mpdf.github.io/) with codeigniter for generating pdf file. 
Everything work perfectly except this [Morris Line Chart](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html). Mpdf can't generate this line chart , it's shows blank space. 
My Controller Look like this.

```
            // load library 
            $this->load->library('pdf'); 
            $pdf = $this->pdf->load();

            $html = $this->load->view('pdf_view', true);

            // render the view into HTML 
            $pdf->WriteHTML(utf8_encode($html)); 
            // write the HTML into the PDF 
            $output_pdf = '/weekly_report_' . date('Y_m_d') . '.pdf'; 
            $pdf->Output("$output_pdf", 'I');
```

In View file look like this , I test this view file , it's working correctly but on mpdf not working

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    "use strict";

    // LINE CHART
    var line = new Morris.Line({
      element: 'line-chart',
      resize: true,
      data: [

        {"daykey": "9 Jul 2014", "milk_value": 3.00},


        {"daykey": "10 Jul 2014", "milk_value": 5.20},


        {"daykey": "11 Jul 2014", "milk_value": 2.40},


        {"daykey": "12 Jul 2014", "milk_value": 8.00},


        {"daykey": "13 Jul 2014", "milk_value": 5.50},


        {"daykey": "14 Jul 2014", "milk_value": 9.00},


        {"daykey": "15 Jul 2014", "milk_value": 9.50},
           ],
      xkey: 'daykey',
      xLabels:'day',
      xLabelMargin: 10,
      xLabelAngle: 90,
      ykeys: ['milk_value'],
      labels: ['Milk Production'],
      parseTime: false,
      lineColors: ['#3c8dbc'],
      hideHover: 'auto',
      pointSize: '0',
      lineWidth: '3',
      resize: true
    });

  });
</script>
```

I tried also [anychart](http://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/gallery/Line,_Spline,_Step-Line_Charts/Line_Chart.php), this one getting same result. How do i embed line chart with mpdf?

Answer (score 0):

mPDF cannot directly plot a SVG generated with Javascript.

You would have to generate the chart SVG source to a string and paste the string to the HTML (or link it as an image). Or try some library that generates static bitmap images.